# dataframe creation from list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lasso-regression

I have a list in R environment named `Vars`, its a *list of 20*. Each `Vars, i=1,2,...,10.` have an output similar to this:

```
     var co
1 (Intercept) 2.446776739
2          x2 1.483926503
3          x8 0.379060372
4         x10 2.330205729
5         x15 1.399578214
```

I want to create a dataframe that contains as output for each `Xi`

where `j` is the coefficients as displayed in `Vars`
and each zet belongs to the coresponding variable Xi

```
>zet
                   x1         x2          x3         x4         x5          x6         x7         x8          x9        x10
        1 0.009704237 0.08319483 0.006421977 0.07528413 0.01538562 0.009653445 0.02759767 0.01827908 0.009425397 0.01119717
             x11        x12        x13        x14        x15        x16       x17        x18       x19        x20
    1 0.01777308 0.02659095 0.01598912 0.01195379 0.01881498 0.02790549 0.0312646 0.01879999 0.0108261 0.01627832
```

I believe that `lapply` is the way to go but i can't figure out how to code it in *R*.

Comment: Can you show first few rows of your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah I edit my question and insert my expected output. Take a look of what i'm trying to create

Comment: What is `λ1`..?

Comment: it is a dataframe of minimum values created by LASSO regression. I edit my question and include the dput(lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply` here :

```
mapply(function(x, y) x*sum(y$coefficient), lambda, ssVarX)
```

Similar with `purrr`'s `map2_dbl` :

```
purrr::map2_dbl(lambda, ssVarX, ~.x * sum(.y$coefficient))
```

Comment: Sorry, thats not what i'm trying to code, check my updated question

Comment: @nickolakis Updated the answer. Can you check if that is what you were looking for?

Comment: I add the absolute value of the coefficients which was what i wanted exactly `mapply(function(x, y) x*abs(sum(y$coefficient)), lambda, ssVarX)`, I f i want to divide each of those values with the number of coefficients existiing in each ssVarX, how this part `mapply(function(x, y) x*abs(sum(y$coefficient)), lambda, ssVarX)` would be?

Comment: You can do it with `sapply` since now we don't need `lambda` i.e `sapply(ssVarX, function(x) sum(x$coefficient)/nrow(x))`

Comment: no, i need lambda inside. I want instead of having `λ`* `sum(y$coefficient)`, to have (`λ* sum(y$coefficient)`) / `ncol(ssVarXi)`, and in the output to divide for X1 with the `nrow(ssVarX1)-1` (i dont want to count the ``intercept` and variable thats why the `-1`

Comment: I don't exactly get it but maybe this? `mapply(function(x, y) x*sum(y$coefficient)/(nrow(y) - 1), lambda, ssVarX)`. Better to ask a new question with required data and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, i fix it by creating a new `mapply` as follows `mapply(function(x, y) x/(nrow(y)-1), lp, ssVarX)`, where `lp` is your `mapply(function(x, y) x*sum(y$coefficient)/(nrow(y) - 1), lambda, ssVarX)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` from `base R`

```
lapply(seq_along(ssVarX), function(i)lambda[i] * sum(ssVarX[[i]]$coefficient))
```